# Manually installing a node module / NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I just discovered about Node Package Manager, so I'm a complete beginner with it.

While looking for a Bootstrap 5 template on the internet, I saw that many of these templates come as packages that look like they are meant to be used with NPM, because they contain a `package.json` file, among others. Those packages can be directly downloaded from the web browser.

So my question is: How am I supposed to properly make use of these browser-downloaded packages?

Because, if those packages do not ALSO exist in the NPM repositories, then manually installing them won't allow me to repair / reinstall them using NPM if the need arises. Installing them by just extracting the files in my project (regardless of whether I manually reference them in `package.json`) doesn't seem like a proper way to install them.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is too broad. Please describe a specific example so it would be easier to help.